# SyncML with Android for Database Sync

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, syncml

I am creating a database sync solution which uses Android clients to 2-way sync the database with a server OTA.

I am presently using

- Android devices with 2.3.6 (switching to a different API level is not an issue, if required)
- the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database on the client side, i.e. the Android devices.
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) database on the server side.

I was exploring some similar, existing solutions, when I came across **[SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML)**, but I couldn't tell if this solution can be used with Android.

So my question is 3 fold:

1. Can I use SyncMl for Android?
2. If yes, how? Can anyone point me to any tutorials, or suggestions, or if someone has developed a similar solution, you could point me in the right direction to start.
3. Is SyncML my best bet? Or should I look for something else?

Comment: There's a few clients (one is open source, Funambol) that uses SyncML (i.e. OMA DS). It's a pretty outdated protocol and you don't really see it that much anymore - it's pretty solidly supported on non-smart phones and Nokias Symbian devices however, so for backwards compatibility it's probably your best bet. If you are making your own client on the smartphone and syncing against your own server - and you're not striving for interoperability with some crappy old Nokia device then you're better off rolling your own solution based on a more sensible format than the ass-backwards OMA DS standard.